# Boolean condition evaluation in apache nifi using expression language doesnt make sense

Tags: apache-nifi

I am new to apache nifi, expression languages. I have a requirement to validate the flow file attribute value and route based on that.

Here is what I have as an requirement.

UPDATE:
Detailed requirement:

- The Nifi workflow will read a json/csv data and process each record at a time. At the moment, we are working with considering the input data in json format.
- Each json object will have attrs as (*i have stripped down few other attrs which are not necessary for my question/this topic*)

```json
{
    "REC_YEAR": 2020,
    "DESCRIPTION": "test",
    "CURRENCY_CD": "USD",
    "CALCULATED_FLAG": "N",
    "CUR_IND": "Y",
    "START_DT": "2020-12-19 17:33:35",
    "END_DT": "9999-12-31 00:00:00"
}
```

- Using "EvaluateJsonPath" processor, I read the json attrs into the flowfile attribute.
- One of the attribute called CURRENCY_CD which can be either NULL/empty or if its not empty, then it should be of length 3 chars --> this is one of the key requirement (for validation of the incoming data).
- So VALID data use cases are CURRENCY_CD can be null, empty or any 3 char string. Any other value for that attr is considered as INVALID input data and route to logging processor flow.
- I am using "UpdateAttribute" processor to evaluate some logic using expression language query and store them under the flowfile attributes.
  [image]
- I came up with the below logic to validate CURRENCY_CD requirement as:

  ${
  ${CURRENCY_CD:isEmpty()}
  :or(${CURRENCY_CD:isEmpty():not():and(${CURRENCY_CD:length():equals(3)})})
  }
- Then i use "RouteOnAttribute" processor to check the value of this attribute and route accordingly to invalid flow (for logging) or pass the incoming data for further processing workflow stages.

**Input data:**
Now, when I supply the input data as empty string in json, I'd expect it to be TRUE. but it ends up in FALSE always. what am I doing wrong here?

Input Sample #1

```json
{
    "CURRENCY_CD": ""
}
```

Input Sample #2

```json
{
    "CURRENCY_CD": null
}
```

For either of these values, empty string or null, nifi marks those respective attributes with values as "Empty string set".
[image]

If I try to break this logic into multiple attributes to check the expression boolean conditions separately, it does evaluates correctly. The Or() condition to combine them is where I expect to be true but it evaluates to false.

[image]

[image]

Then, i tried using like this as well,
[image]

```java
${
    ${Is-CURRENCY_CD-Empty:equals(true)}
    :or(${Is-CURRENCY_CD-NotEmptyAndLen3:equals(true)})
}
```

and store it in an attr "Is_CurrencyCode_Valid" and expect it to be true, but in turn, it comes with false.
[image]

Comment: A screenshot of your flow would help. You are using a RouteOnAttribute to route FlowFiles depending on CURRENCY_CD being empty or not?

Comment: I have updated the question with more details and steps on what i do, how i perform the flow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bit diffcult to understand your post - could do with being a bit more clear.

[RouteOnAttribute](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.12.1/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.RouteOnAttribute/index.html) takes one or more Dynamic Properties with some [Expression Language](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/expression-language-guide.html) that must evaluate to True or False.

If the Dynamic Property's Expression Language evaluates to True, the FlowFile is directed to a Relationship with the name of the Dynamic Property.

If the Dynamic Property's Expression Language evaluates to False, it will try the next Dynamic Property (if there is one) - if there are no more Dynamic Properties left, and all have returned False, then the FlowFile is sent to the `unmatched` Relationship.

If your data is *always* either null/empty (Negative) or contains 3 chars (Positive) then there is no need to check for both conditions - simply check for either the Negative or Positive condition.

E.g.

One Dynamic Property called `valid` with the expression `${CURRENCY_CD:length():equals(3)}`

With this configuration, all FlowFiles where `CURRENCY_CD` has 3 characters will be routed to the `valid` Relationship. All FlowFiles that *do not* have 3 characters, including null/empty, will be routed to the `unmatched` Relationship.

With that, the following would happen:

`CURRENCY_CD` = `TRI` goes to `valid`

`CURRENCY_CD` = `null` goes to `unmatched`

`CURRENCY_CD` = `testing` goes to `unmatched` (we are assuming here that this won't be present in your data)

If you can't make that guarantee and some data might fall outside of those 2 conditions, you could add a second Dynamic Property named `empty` with the expression `${CURRENCY_CD:isEmpty()}`. This would route all null/empty FlowFiles to the Relationship `empty`.

With that, the following would happen:

`CURRENCY_CD` = `TRI` goes to `valid`

`CURRENCY_CD` = `null` goes to `empty`

`CURRENCY_CD` = `testing` goes to `unmatched`

It's hard to tell from your post, but if both empty/null and 3 characters are the Postive condition and you want to validate for both in one Expression then you can simplify your Expression to this:

```
${CURRENCY_CD:isEmpty():or(${CURRENCY_CD:length():equals(3)})}
```

Which would return True for both empty/null or 3 characters and forward them to the same Relationship.

With that, the following would happen:

`CURRENCY_CD` = `TRI` goes to `valid`

`CURRENCY_CD` = `null` goes to `valid`

`CURRENCY_CD` = `testing` goes to `unmatched`

Comment: Thanks @Sdairs, the above solution (very last one) worked like charm. Simple enough and solved my need. I guess, i over complicated the logic, but thinking about the logical flow, why it still didnt work? although the break up of logic as separate attrs are all valid but combining them to do an OR condition ends up in FALSE... thats where i am not convinced..

Comment: Glad it worked - if it solved your issue, please accept the answer :)  I'm surprised that your original Expression Language was actually valid syntax - the `or()` function must be chained to a previous function, which I didn't think could be an Expression `${}` - but I haven't tested that, maybe someone else can chime in there. You can see examples of using `or()` in the EL docs https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/expression-language-guide.html#or